# How do I include 3rd party libraries in a Yii Console Application?

Tags: php, yii, filepath

I can include a 3rd party library in a normal Yii Web Application by including these lines at the top of the controller file:

```
Yii::import('application.vendors.*');
require_once('library/file.php');

class AController extends Controller {
...
```

I'd like to include a 3rd party library in a separate Console Application as well.  However, doing something like this at the top of that file does no good:

```
Yii::import('application.vendors.*');
require_once('library/file.php');

class ACommand extends CConsoleCommand {
...
```

It complains of "No such file or directory."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

why not you specify the path in relation to the current file or relation to root.  something like this

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/../library/file.php");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this (file structure: 'protected/library')

require_once(Yii::app()->basePath . '/library/file.php');